# Handling failed to load chunks webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am using webpack generating a manifest file which I inline into html. Everything works fine except for a case like this:

Say there's an app with these files:

```
home.component.html
home.component.js
home.controller.js

settings.component.html
settings.component.js
settings.controller.js
```

each component.js file requires the component's controller:

```
module.exports = {
    templateUrl: require("!file-loader!./home.component.html"),
    controller: require("./home.controller")
}
```

Assume user has just opened the website and only has the home component files loaded (because other files are downloaded on demand).

Lets  also assume that I push a change to settings controller to the server and the settings controller is rebuilt and gets a new file name (chunkhash).

This is a problem since the manifest file that is inlined in the page user has opened is old and has the old filename of the settings controller and when the app will try to require it, it will fail.

(It's hard to replicate, the issue may be when modifying and requiring the template file)

What could be the possible solutions to this problem?